# Why are Market Cap Categories Not Consistent?

Tags: terminology, stock-valuation, fidelity, market-capitalization

According to [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/investing/market-capitalization-defined/), a "small cap" company is between $300M and $2Bn. However, on Fidelity, companies are marked as being "micro cap" until they have a market cap greater than $2Bn. Only companies above $2Bn are marked as "small cap".

Similarly, companies are defined by Investopedia as being "mid-cap" from $2-10Bn, but on Fidelity, the "medium cap" range seems to extend up to $50Bn.

Why are these categories not coherent across the industry? Is one set of categories considered authoritative over others? Is there a list that is maintained by any industry authority body that updates in response to inflation? When were these categories first proposed and is there an example of these categories changing in the past?

Comment: Have you asked either of the two companies why they use the terms differently?

Comment: @keshlam No, I haven't reached out to Fidelity support or contacted Investopedia. The way the Investopedia article I linked is written, it makes it sound like these categories are respected industry-wide, hence my confusion.

Comment: This may depend on whether that particular publisher separates small-cap and mid-cap, or groups those together as "not large-cap, therefore small-cap".